Neovim: with auto-session, how can I restore Neotree's position to where it was before closing Neovim?
I have no idea what I'm doing, When I just have nvim and Auto session setup individually and I quit Neovim, auto session restores a blank window in place of Neotree. I have this snippet in my init.lua with pre_save_cmds = { 'Neotree close' }, post_restore_cmds = { 'Neotree buffers' } but if I move the window and reopen nvim then it just reopens to the left. Here's my whole init.lua:
vim.g.base46_cache = vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/nvchad/base46/"
vim.g.mapleader = " "

-- bootstrap lazy and all plugins
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath "data" .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"

if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  local repo = "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git"
  vim.fn.system { "git", "clone", "--filter=blob:none", repo, "--branch=stable", lazypath }
end

vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

local lazy_config = require "configs.lazy"

-- load plugins
require("lazy").setup({
  {
    "NvChad/NvChad",
    lazy = false,
    branch = "v2.5",
    import = "nvchad.plugins",
    config = function()
      require "options"
    end,
  },
  { import = "plugins" },
}, lazy_config)

require("auto-session").setup {
  auto_save_enabled = true,
  auto_restore_enabled = true,
  auto_session_enable_last_session = true,
  pre_save_cmds = { 'Neotree close' },
  post_restore_cmds = { 'Neotree buffers' },
}

require("auto-save").setup {
  -- your config goes here
  -- or just leave it empty :)
}

require("neo-tree").setup({
  source_selector = {
      winbar = false,
      statusline = false
  }
})

-- load theme
dofile(vim.g.base46_cache .. "defaults")
dofile(vim.g.base46_cache .. "statusline")

require "nvchad.autocmds"

vim.schedule(function()
  require "mappings"
end)

​

I'm trying to solve this session thing myself. Using rmagatti/auto-session plugin. The standard SessionRestore and SessionSave keymaps are working. The autosession and save/restore by name not so much. But I'm sharing because this might lead you to a viable solution
return {
    "rmagatti/auto-session",
    config = function()
        local auto_session = require("auto-session")

        auto_session.setup({
            auto_restore_enabled = false,
            auto_session_suppress_dirs = { "~/", "~/Dev/", "~/Downloads", "~/Documents", "~/Desktop/" },
            auto_session_root_dir = "/Users/x-tthompson/build/sessions/", -- Sessions are stored here
        })

        local keymap = vim.keymap
        local session_root = auto_session.conf.auto_session_root_dir

        keymap.set("n", "<leader>wr", "<cmd>SessionRestore<CR>", { desc = "Restore session for cwd" }) -- restore last workspace session for current directory
        keymap.set("n", "<leader>ws", "<cmd>SessionSave<CR>", { desc = "Save session for auto session root dir" }) -- save workspace session for current working directory
        keymap.set("n", "<leader>wsr", "<cmd>Autosession search<CR>", { desc = "Search sessions" })

        -- Custom commands to save and restore sessions with names
        keymap.set("n", "<leader>wsn", function()
            vim.ui.input({ prompt = "Session Name: " }, function(input)
                if input then
                    local session_path = session_root .. input
                    vim.cmd("SessionSave " .. session_path)
                end
            end)
        end, { desc = "Save session with name" })

        keymap.set("n", "<leader>wrn", function()
            vim.ui.input({ prompt = "Session Name: " }, function(input)
                if input then
                    local session_path = session_root .. input
                    vim.cmd("SessionRestoreFromFile " .. session_path)
                end
            end)
        end, { desc = "Restore session with name" })
    end,
}

